# How to set the android 6.0 mock location app from adb

Tags: android

I would like to set the "`mock location app`" without any user intervention so I can partially automate some tests on Android 6.0.

`geo fix` is not appropriate in my situation.

Is it possible?

Comment: I meet this problem, too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For Android 6.0+:

**Allowing app for mock locaiton**

```
adb shell appops set <PACKAGE> android:mock_location allow
```

**Removing app for mock location**

```
adb shell appops set <PACKAGE> android:mock_location deny
```

**Checking if app is set for mock location**

```
adb shell appops get <PACKAGE> android:mock_location
```

Comment: additional info: to get the current user id (multu user) you have to run `adb shell dumpsys activity | grep mCurrentUser`. The id can be used in the --user switch of appops set/get now to set/get options for/from a specific user. e.g. `adb shell appops get --user <USER-ID> <PACKAGE> android:mock_location`.

Answer (score 0):

The best my team and I could do is to create a separate app that sets mock locations. This app is launched from the test suite. We use UI automator to launch the mock location app. The only caveat here is that you need to manually install the mock location app once and manually set it as the mock locations app once.

Comment: Yes, I have installed the [Fake GPS location](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps&hl=en) app to set the lat/long, and can do this automatically via `adb install`, but the part I want to automate is configuring the system to use it.