# How can I fake a location for my wear OS device?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am looking for a way to fake the location for my android wear OS device in order to debug my app.
I am talking about a real physical device, not the emulator.

Comment: You try isntall a fake location app? Try `Fake GPS Location Spoofer` for example

Answer (score 0):

You may connect with adb to your Wear device and then [mock location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40414011/how-to-set-the-android-6-0-mock-location-app-from-adb):

```
adb shell appops set <PACKAGE> android:mock_location allow
```

There is a ready [solution on github](https://github.com/amotzte/android-mock-location-for-development)